# Powershell - Get contents of a log file, the log name is stored using current date

Tags: powershell

I need to setup monitoring of a log files using solarwinds, before i can do this i need to read the contents of the log file into Solarwinds. The log files are saved in "c:\logs" but the logfile name changes everyday - it appends the current date to the end of the logfile name for example *logfile***20130602**.log. Can you please help i need to be able to read these logs files using powershell.

Answer (score 3):

You can access the .NET DateTime object and format your date accordingly. This gives you the filename of the current log:

```
> 'C:\logs\log' + [System.DateTime]::Now.ToString('yyyyMMdd') + '.log'
C:\logs\log20130206.log
```

And you can get the contents using `Get-Content`

```
Get-Content ('C:\logs\log' + [System.DateTime]::Now.ToString('yyyyMMdd') + '.log')
```

#### Edit

Just noticed that you would want to use `yyyyddMM` as the date format instead, not the sane one ;P

Comment: Thank you, thats perfect - extactly what i needed